Connection to oracle database using cx_Oracle fails with "ORA-12569: TNS:packet checksum failure" error
When using python cx_Oracle getting error "ORA-12569: TNS:packet checksum failure" error,
Where as connection using sqlplus is working without any error where we use same tns-string
sqlplus sys@ as sysdba is working and tnsping is also working.
Python version is 3.9.18
We tried to use os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] in python script but same error is observed. Below is sample error message
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user=username, password=password, dsn=dsn, mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12569: TNS:packet checksum failure

(i) You can't set LD_LIBRARY_PATH after a process starts. (ii) the fact that Python gave that error means that it did find Oracle client libraries. (iii) are you running SQL*Plus and Python in exactly the same terminal window, and using the same Oracle client libraries? (update your question with more information) (iv) In general you shouldn't be using cx_Oracle since it was renamed/replaced by python-oracledb several years ago
